# Can I use a real object that implements ToolsAPI's IOTAEditPosition in a DUnit test?

Tags: delphi, dunit, toolsapi

I'm writing a set of wizards to enhance source code editing in the IDE and the text manipulation is done through `IOTAEditPosition` which I get from `BorlandIDEServices`.

How can I automate tests against my methods so I can assert that the text manipulation was done right? `IOTAEditPosition` can't be stubbed or mocked because I would like to simulate the same environment of production code (the real `IOTAEditPosition` does some automatic work with indentation, line breaks, it has several methods like checking to see if a character is an identifier or a word separator, text search mechanisms and so on, it really does a lot of things that are specific to the IDE editor).

In this case, I don't care about puritanism like *Unit vs Integration test*. Call it integration test if you will, the fact is that my code totally depends and it's very sensible to the behavior of `IOTAEditPosition` and I need to test them together.

Just to make it a bit more clear. In my mind, the ideal assertion would be something like:

```
// DUnit test case
MyObject.LoadText(SampleText);
MyObject.ManipulateText;
CheckEquals(ExpectedManipulatedText, MyObject.GetManipulatedText);
```

As the actual underlying text manipulation is done by IOTAEditPosition, I need an implementation of it that behaves exactly like the one I get in production code.

Comment: Sounds like you need something that will automate operation of the IDE itself, like TestComplete. Them it's the IDE providing the implementation of that interface.

Comment: Why  can't you mock IOTAEditPosition

Comment: @DavidHeffernan let me give a simple example: I have a routine that duplicates a line of code. I'd like my test to check if the end result is ok, if the 2 lines are the same, with the same indentation, etc. The real IOTAEditPosition indents code automatically when I add a line break so the duplicated line could end up with extra indentation. My code is _very sensible_ to nuances like that... I can't create a mock because I'm not even sure of what is the exact behavior of the real IDE object.

Comment: If you don't know how the real object behaves, and you want to develop against that behaviour, then I'd say that testing is the least of your worries.

Comment: Well, I think tests are a great tool when I'm not sure how something will behave. I write the tests and rely on them to tell me if I'm on the right track. Maybe I'm getting this wrong, Actually I always create mocks to test my objects in isolation, but I think IOTAEditPosition is too complex, there are too much details and a mock would have to make too much assumptions. If I could just test the integration of my code together with the real IOTAEditPosition, things would be way simpler and the test code would be way smaller.

Comment: You're confusing multiple kinds of tests. When you're not sure how Delphi will behave, you test it, but it's really more of an *experiment*. Once you learn Delphi's behavior, you write unit tests to check that when you call one of *your* functions, it calls the correct sequence of functions from Delphi's objects. Use mocks for that, but don't try to check the result of the changed text. Just check that your code invoked the right interfaces. Finally, write integration tests to confirm that when the correct functions are called in your code, the correct output is produced in Delphi.

Comment: @RobKennedy And how can I make these _experiments_ if I don't have the object and run the tests against it? I think creating a mock for this would be impracticable. If I have a method that calls 50 methods of IOTAEditPosition (and I will have methods like this), what do I do, check if all the 50 calls were made in the right order with the right parameters? There are times where a low level integration test is way simpler than pure unit tests. Now, if I can't have the implementation of IOTAEditPosition, I can't do the experiments you said neither I can write the integration test.